# Merging 2 Graphics-objects into Duplex page

Tags: c#

We have a WinForm-Program, which send a currently shown page to a printer.
This is done pretty straightforward: We create a PrintDocument object and on the PrintPage event we fill the graphics object:

```
    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        _renderObject.RenderPrinter(e.Graphics);
    }
```

I'm not sure if this approach is still state of the art, but the program is quite old and still running, so it seems to work.
The problem now: We need to create a duplex-page and print some stuff on the backside.

My first approach was to create a second Form initialized by the first form and on the PrintPage event I write the graphics-stuff, something like this:

```
public static class Printer
{
    private static Graphics _e1;
    private static Graphics _e2;

    public static void Print(Graphics e1, Graphics e2)
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        _e1 = e1;
        _e2 = e2;
        pd.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Horizontal;

        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
    }

    static void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        _renderObject.RenderPrinter(_e1);
        _renderObject.RenderPrinter(_e2);
    }
}
```

I guess I'd have to basically set the size of the first page to exactly A4 to assure the second object is printed on the backside.

But is this really the right way to do this? Are nowadays easier solutions arround to create a duplex page without a need to set every control manually? Or is my approach the only possible to make stuff happen?

As usual thanks in advance

Matthias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen so far, the back side is basically just another page, and the duplex setting causes it to be printed on the back (if the printer supports it).

The `PrintPage` callback is called once for every page. The `PrintPageEventArgs` object has a `HasMorePages` property, which you can set to true to signal that there are more pages that must be printed. Note that it also has a `Graphics` property, so there's no need to pass around extra `Graphics` objects.

So just render the front side in the first call to `PrintPage` and set `HasMorePages` to true. The second time `PrintPage` gets called you'll render the back side and set `HasMorePages` to false. That does mean that you'll have to keep track of which side you're printing. Sadly, `PrintPageEventArgs` does not contain any custom state, so that might be a little tricky. You could use a static variable, but that's going to break if you ever start a print-job while another is still being rendered.

To solve this, I would use a closure, an anonymous function that captures the local variable `page`:

```
int page = 0;
pd.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (page == 0)
    {
        // Print front side
        _renderObject.RenderPrinter(e.Graphics);
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
    else if (page == 1)
    {
        // TODO: Print back side
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }

    page += 1;
};
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I think I can work with that. To be honest, I was never fan to print WinForms directly, but I can't afford to recreate the whole project.